# How can I format time in excel from 2017-02-17 01:59:57 UTC?

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, excel-2010, timing

How can I change the format of this: 2017-02-17 01:59:57 UTC

To look like this in Excel: 1:59 AM

Bottom Line: I'm trying to create a graph consisting of a certain (y) variable and the (x) variable being time 12:00 AM - 12:00 PM.

Comment: Surely that time would refer to `1:59 AM`, rather than `PM`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `UTC` before Excel can recognize the string as a date/time. This should work:

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"UTC",""),"h:mm am/pm")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the time then,

```
=TIMEVALUE(MID(A7, 11, 8))
```

If you want the date and time but only show the time then,

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A7,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A7,11,8))
```

In either case, format the cell as `h:mm AM/PM;@` to show `1:59 PM`. This produces a true time or datetime value; not text-that-looks-like-time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try formula below (assuming data is in A1, you may need to modify)

```
=IF(HOUR(A1)>12,CONCAT(IF(HOUR(A1)>12,HOUR(A1)-12),":",MINUTE(A1),"PM"),CONCAT(HOUR(A1),":",MINUTE(A1),"AM"))
```